# How to apply plugin to allprojects with new Gradle plugins mechanism?

Tags: gradle

Before Gradle 2.1 I could apply plugin to all projects by using `allProjects` closure (by prevoisly resolving the jar, of course):

```groovy
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.0.1"
  }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}
```

With new publishing mechanism it looks like the `plugins` closure can't be used inside `allprojects`:

```groovy
allprojects {

    plugins {
        id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "3.0.1"
    }
}
```

fails with:

*"Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_xxxx_run_closure1_closure4@yyyyy] on root project"*

What are the rules of using `plugins` closure? Is the plugin applied to current project only? If so, how can I apply it to all projects without repeating the `plugins` closure inside each build?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The new `plugins {...}` syntax cannot be used within a `allprojects {...}` or `subprojects {...}` closure. Additionally, it can only be used within build scripts (no script plugins, init scripts, etc). If you want to avoid having to apply the plugin to each project individually I'd suggest using the old notation. This is an issue the Gradle team is aware of and a solution will be introduced in future versions.

**Update:** Starting with Gradle 3.0 you can do this in a slightly modified way. You still have to explicitly use `apply()` but you no longer have to deal with all the `buildscript { }` nonsense to get the plugin on your classpath. This also allows you to conditionally apply plugins. Check out the Gradle 3.0 [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes#improved-plugins-dsl) for more information.

```
plugins {
    id 'my.special.plugin' version '1.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'my.special.plugin'
}
```

Comment: New closure syntax is the only way to make sonarqube plugin work and cant make the new plugins closure syntax work for my project because of above error. No wonder JVM languages get a bad name for poor infrastructure for such basic stuff. Note :- In my case, plugins closure is outside all snippets just after the old apply plugin code.